# Conditional tags in play 2.0 templates

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a template with paramaters

```
@(title: Html, topbar: Html, nav: String = "")(content: Html)
```

I use the @title tag to set both a title for the page and a page header i.e.:

```
<div class="header">
<h1>@title</h1> 
</div>
```

However, Some pages I dont want to put a header/title in so i leave them blank and tried:

```
@if(title != {}){
    <div class="header">
    <h1>@title</h1> 
    </div>
}
```

But this does not work..
How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass `null` value in the controller, in actions that shouldn't use the `title` and then check if `title != null`

```
@if(title != null){
    <div class="header">
    <h1>@title</h1> 
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What if I had specific values I wanted to ignore, something like 
@if(title != {Home})

Comment: I tried @if(title != Html("Home")) but this still returns false

Comment: Why does your title have a `Html` type while as I suppose it's common `String`?

Comment: As I wrote :) You are setting your title in the `controller` and than passing to the `view` most probably you can check in the controller level if it's allowed, and if isn't just put `null` instead the value. I think that's better solution than building complex condition in the views. In controller you can use many kinds of matching in the view possibilities are limited.